# add Custom text field in single product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am working on a project in woocommerce.

Can anyone help me to add a custom text field next to "add to cart"?

I tried the following but it is not working.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'add_custom_field', 0 );

function add_custom_field() {
    global $post;

    echo "<div class='prod-code'>Product Code: ";
    $text= get_field('txt-field', $post);
    echo "</div>";

    return true;
}
```

Comment: If you mean a custom text input then you should consider [Product Add-Ons](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try using `$post->ID` like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'add_custom_field', 0 );

function add_custom_field() {
    global $post;

    echo "<div class='prod-code'>Product Code: ";
    $text= get_field('txt-field', $post->ID);
    echo "</div>";

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This error i am facing..Product Code: 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_field() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\dayhit\functions.php on line 230

Comment: `get_field()` is not a default WordPress function. But it is what you have in your original question so it was easy to assume that you were using a plugin that provides this function.

Comment: @selvakumar are you using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin?

Comment: @MichaelDoye post id is not a good idea if you use product variable will allow you to access other property as well.

Answer (score 0):

put your html code inside content-product.php (wp-content/themes/YOUR THEME/woocommerce/content-product.php)
content-product.php contains code of list page in wordpress. if you want to edit product page than edit content-single-product.php.

Comment: no it will not store in database. for that you have to write code according to your need. i just told you a flow.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Woocommerce there are two case :

1. You are reading post ID
2. You want to display a SKU

You can implement it via single function :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_productCode', 5 );
function display_productCode(){
    global $product;
    echo 'SKU: ' . $product->get_sku();
    echo 'Product ID:'.$product->get_id();

}
```